# how to serializeArray() with name for array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, serialization

I have this HTML code :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="search-form[filters][category][12]" value="cat-12" autocomplete="off" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="search-form[filters][category][14]" value="cat-14" autocomplete="off" checked="checked" />
```

When I´m using the jQuery function `serializeArray()` like this :

```
var $postForm = $("#myForm");
console.dir( $postForm.serializeArray() );
```

I got this :

```
[
  {
    "name": "search-form[filters][category][12]",
    "value": "cat-12"
  },
  {
    "name": "search-form[filters][category][14]",
    "value": "cat-14"
  }
]
```

How can I get this :

```
[
    {
      "search-form"{
             "filters" : {
                   "category" : {
                            "12" : { "value" : "cat-12" },
                            "14" : { "value" : "cat-14" }
                    }
              }  
         }    
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following git repository may solve your problem.

https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON

> Form input, textarea and select tags are supported. Nested attributes and arrays can be specified by using the attr[nested][nested] syntax.